# What is the proper place for upload logic in a MEAN stack application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, upload

So i'm trying to wrap my head around developing full applications with the MEAN stack (mongodb, express, angular, node.js).

I understand that using express and node i can create a rest api with endpoints to grab data for my app. I also understand that angular is for FRONT END only. So my question is this... when you have something like an upload form and you want to upload an image to the server, would you want to create an api endpoint called something like "/api/upload/" and have all your logic for uploading the image inside that endpoint, or would you want all that upload logic somewhere else and then simply provide the file name to the "/api/upload/" endpoint with a post request?

Comment: what do you mean by "upload logic somewhere else", a thrid-party service, as mentionned by @Xavdidtheshadow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by upload logic - there isn't much needed, but I would put everything (including the file itself) in a `POST` to `/api/upload/`, then save it however you wish to within that function.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a better approach to put your business logic at server side and I suggest you to follow this approach. If you are following this approach you can easily manipulate images if required. for e.g while uploading an logo or avatar sometime we need to crop,re-size etc operations on image like same image is used for thumbnail and profile picture. Here this approach is very meaning full for us. we can give response to the user and create a new process for image manipulation without waiting or notifying end user. Most of the apps following this approach for better experience

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a **separation of concerns**, first of you can delegate the file upload to the client to be more "user friendly", crop it, resize it and then post the resulting file as "a file" or base64 to the server for storing it either in the database or to the file system.

I'd recommend a combination of these two libraries for the client:

[Angular File Upload](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/) and [ngImgCrop](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop)

[image: crop image]

then you can post the image and use a body parser to "catch" the image in express I'd recommend you to use [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) and it could be part of an endpoint as you mentioned like **api/file/upload** for example

```
// your controller
exports.uploadDocument = function(req,res, next){
        req.pipe(req.busboy);
        req.busboy.on('file',function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, contentType){
            // implementation
        });

        //updating req.body with busboy parameters
        req.busboy.on('field',function(fieldname,val){
            req.body[fieldname] = val;
        });

        req.busboy.on('finish', function() {
            // implementation
                next();
        });
};
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: express should do the upload, but it doesn't have to.

Long answer: It's a design question. If it was an image, you could have angular post the image to the imgur api and send that returned url to your server, but that's *much* more unreliable than doing it server-side. People could be using your site from phones, tablets, etc and though image uploading is fairly fast and consistent, the server will always do it the fastest of all because it doesn't depend on the client's wireless connection strength. Angular and Express are equally good at validating the image file.

**Most importantly**, if something goes wrong, you'll want to log the attempt (and maybe the image) are mostly unable to do that on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advice you move your logic to the backend and do it with express,

- More secure, as the code is not expose on the client browser
- Fast uploading (though can be fast on the client side too, but if the client browser is slow, it would relatively affect the uploading)
- Reduce the code exposed to the client browser